# Remove DataColumn from DataTable with Data

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datacolumn

I have Datatable with Data. I called my postgres data base and get DataTable.

```
// get the new data from postgres
   var dataTable = pg.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM " + '"'+table+'"');
```

Now I need to remove specific Column. assume that there are 5 columns with data.

```
ID     |   Name   | Address | Mobile | Home
_______________________________________________
    1  |  A       |AAA      | 123    | 345
    2  |  B       |BBB      | 234    | 456
    3  |  C       |CCC      | 345    | 567
```

So I need to remove "Home " DataColumn and Recreate this DataTable as following

```
  ID   |   Name   | Address | Mobile 
____________________________________
    1  |  A       |AAA      | 123    
    2  |  B       |BBB      | 234    
    3  |  C       |CCC      | 345
```

How can I do this ?

Appreciate your comments.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need the Home column between the query and when you want the column removing? If not, why not just select the columns in the SELECT statement rather than them all with the asterisk

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is really small piece of my code. So I need to remove specific column. this is not only for one table. :)

Comment: Can't you just skip selecting it? It seems like your table already needs special treatment so maybe a generic sql select is not appropriate.

Comment: Ok, so what if you create a new datatable and copy your data over to the new one? Or maybe as Tim Schmelter suggests. :)

Comment: I would follow Taosique's answer, but whats the reason for removing that column anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the columns you need explicitly rather than selecting unneeded columns and removing them afterwards:

```
SELECT "Id", "Name", "Address", "Mobile"
```

Using `SELECT *` is bad manners because it makes your contract with database unstable - should column configuration change you will get unpredictable result.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the method [`DataTable.Columns.Remove(string name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcdez2aw(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dataTable.Columns.Remove("Home");
```

Then the table doesn't contain this column anymore and all rows' data in this column is thrown away. However,  omit  this column in the first place and list the desired columns:

```
var dataTable = pg.GetDataTable("SELECT ID, Name, Address, Mobile FROM " + '"'+ table +'"');
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using
`dataTable.Columns.Remove("ColumnName")`
or
`dataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(ColumnNumber)`

Comment: This does not differ substantially from other answers, which have the additional positive of explanation of the code.